# how to avoid this error in ssrs reports result Set?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am getting this error while dividing the two column Values in ssrs report.

1.OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate = 0.00

2.UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate = 0.00

These are the values I am Getting.

But If I put this expression I am getting #Error in result set for this expression.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value) = 0.00 OR 
Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value) = 0.00, 0, 
Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value) /Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value))
```

Can anyone Suggest Me where I am doing wrong.Please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

SSRS evaluates all of the possible output values in an IIF expression, regardless of whether the condition is true or false.  Your expression needs to look as follows:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value) = 0.00 
    OR Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value) = 0.00, 0, 
    Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value) / IIF(Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value)=0.00,1,Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare the Dataset name for each field.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value, "DatasetName") = 0.00,0,IIF(
Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value, "DatasetName") = 0.00, 0, 
Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value, "DatasetName") /Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value,"DatasetName")))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply bro,

Comment: =IIF(Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value,"dsSalesActivities") = 0.00 OR Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value,"dsSalesActivities") = 0.00, 0, Sum(Fields!OccupiedUnitsAtEndOfDate.Value,"dsSalesActivities") / Sum(Fields!UnitCapacityAtEndOfDate.Value,"dsSalesActivities"))  I put like this but now also it throws error only.

Comment: can anyone help me on this..is there any text box properties issue or some other else

Comment: Try the edited expression, I used two IIFs instead of OR.

Comment: I expect that this will not work, even as modified.  SSRS evaluates both of the possible output values in an IIF expression, regardless of whether the condition is true or false.